# How to store global response data from server for use in Android application

Tags: android

The first , I use retrofit to fetch user data from server , In app have user model, and user model have to use many place in application. How to store user object data for call everyplace in application.

Example

1. fetch user data from api
2. fragment A , B ---> have to use user data for binding to view.

Question

1. How to store and call user data ?
2. How to notify view when object user data change (fill data to view again when user object data change)?

Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You should look into Room.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) It's a first-party ORM wrapper around SQLite that provides exactly what you want - live updates as your data changes. For example, you can insert your User object in the database and set listeners on that object (by using the `@Query` annotation). Any time that User is updated, all of your listeners will be notified and you can handle the changes as needed.

Comment: I want a sample about when object user change and how to use the object from db. Thank very much